# Get the total element count of multiple arrays

Tags: perl

I can get the element count of an array by assigning it to a scalar:

```
my $size = @array1;
```

How could I get the total size of 5 arrays at the same time?

```
my $size = @array1,@array2,@array3,@array4,@array5;
```

Comment: What behaviour are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want sum of arrays length,

```
my $size = @array1 + @array2 + @array3 + @array4 + @array5;
```

or less efficient alternatives,

```
# in scalar context map returns number of elements
my $size = map 1, @array1,@array2,@array3,@array4,@array5;

# make new array and dereference it (in scalar context)
my $size = @{[ @array1,@array2,@array3,@array4,@array5 ]};
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried that? What was the result? Note that your option 1 is equivalent to

```
my $size = @array5;
```

as you create a new variable each time.

I assumed you wanted the size of all the arrays together.

Arrays return they size in scalar context. Lists don't, they return their last element.

Therefore,

```
my $size = (@array1, @array2);
```

returns the size of @array2. (Without parentheses, it returns the size of @array1).

You can use

```
my $size = @array1 + @array2;
```

The + operator forces scalar context.

If you instead want an array of sizes, use

```
my @sizes = map scalar @$_, \@array1, \@array2;
```